Is there any connection between two unitaries whose norm are close?
Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra. Suppose $u$ and $v$ are two untaries in $A$ with $\Vert u-v\Vert<\delta$. Does the following holds?
\begin{equation}
 sp\left(v\right)\subset \{z\in S^1: dist\left(z,sp\left(u\right)\right)<\delta\}
\end{equation}.
Furthermore, suppose $u^*u=uu^*=v^*v=vv^*=p$, where $p$ is a projection in $A$. Does the above relation holds

Assume ${\rm dist}(z,\sigma(u))\ge \delta.$ We have
$$\|(ze-u)^{-1}\|=\max\{|z-w|^{-1}\,:\, w\in \sigma(u)\}
\le \delta^{-1}$$ because $|z-w|\ge \delta.$ Next
$ ze-v=ze-u-(v-u),$ hence
$$(ze-v)(ze-u)^{-1}=e-(v-u)(ze-u)^{-1}$$ and
$$\|(v-u)(ze-u)^{-1}\|\le \|u-v\|\|(ze-u)^{-1}\|<\delta\,\delta^{-1}=1 $$ Therefore $(ze-v)(ze-u)^{-1}$ is invertible. Hence $ze-v$ is invertible, i.e. $z\notin\sigma(v).$ By contraposition $z\in \sigma(v)$ implies ${\rm dist}(z,\sigma(u))<\delta.$
Concerning the second part the relations imply that $up=pu=u$ and $vp=pv=v.$ Then you may apply  the first part to the unital $C^*$-algebra $\widetilde{A}=pAp.$ To this end observe that $$\sigma_A(u)=\{0\}\cup \sigma_{\widetilde{A}}(u)$$

Thank you very much for your answer. The critical point of the answer is the unitary is normal, and hence we can use functional calculus to estimate the norm of the inverse of $ze-u$ for $dist\left(z,\sigma\left(u\right)\right)<\delta$. Thus we can make a further estimation. Thank you again.
